# IndexError:Index 10 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 10

Tags: python-3.x, keras, conv-neural-network

I am classifying images into 30 different classes using CNN and on running the CNN ,I am getting the following traceback-

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "thapar.py", line 165, in <module>
Y = np_utils.to_categorical(labels, num_classes)
File "/home/rishav/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/utils/np_utils.py", line 31, in to_categorical
categorical[np.arange(n), y] = 1
IndexError: index 10 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 10
```

Python 3.6
Keras 2.1.5 using tensorflow backend
Ubuntu 16.04

I have explored other similar questions but unable to find the similarity in issue.

How to resolve this issue?

Edit:

```
num_classes = 30
num_of_samples = img_data.shape[0]
labels = np.ones((num_of_samples,),dtype='int64')
labels[0:20]=0
labels[20:40]=1
labels[40:60]=2
labels[60:80]=3
labels[80:100]=4
labels[100:120]=5
labels[120:140]=6
labels[140:160]=7
labels[160:180]=8
labels[180:200]=9
labels[200:220]=10
labels[220:240]=11
labels[240:260]=12
labels[260:280]=13
labels[280:300]=14
labels[300:320]=15
labels[320:340]=16
labels[340:360]=17
labels[360:380]=18
labels[380:400]=19
labels[400:420]=20
labels[420:440]=21
labels[440:460]=22
labels[460:480]=23
labels[480:500]=24
labels[500:520]=25
labels[520:540]=26
labels[540:560]=27
labels[560:580]=28
labels[580:600]=29

names =
```

`['bent','bowl','claw','fist','good','thumbs_up','A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y']`

```
Y = np_utils.to_categorical(labels, num_classes)
```

Comment: Please share the isolated code related to your problem. (what does `labels` and `num_classes` contain?)

Comment: Edited ,please check

Comment: Your code is working for me, generating `Y` of shape `(600, 30)` as expected. However, according to your error trace, it seems to me you were using `num_classes = 10` with `labels` containing values above `9`.

Answer (score 0):

Recently, I have faced the same problem, then I got to know it was giving error with some images only, I remove those images and it worked perfectly for me then.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31043795)